# Adding max(value)+1 in new row, can this be a problem?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

In a SQL Server table I have the following 2 columns:

**RowId**: primary key, numaric, identity column and auto insert.
**MailId**: Non key, numaric, non identity and non auto insert.

Mail Id can be duplicate. In case of new MailId I will check max(MailId)+1 and insert it in new row and in case of duplication value will be coming as parameter.

Logic looks fine but here is an issue, I was just considering (yet chacnes of accurance are ver low) In the same time there can be two different new MailId requests. Can this casue logical error ? For example when code checked max(MailId)+1 was 101 and I stored it in a variable but may be before next insert statment executs a new record inserted in table. Now max(MailId)+1 in table will be 102 but value in variable will be 101 ?

Any suggestion please I want to control this error chances as well.

**EDIT**

(I am not using identity(1,1) because I also have to pass custom values in it)

Comment: you can lock table for reading unless you insert max(mailid)+1

Comment: So I guess it depends if MailId can have duplicates or not.  You mention they can be duplicate.  Yes, the scenario you mentioned *can* happen.  Identity columns /w auto increment (such as your RowId) have functionality built-in to prevent something like this from happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you use a custom-rolled `Identity` field when there is such a great one already in SQL Server?

Just use `INT Identity (1,1)` for your ID field and it will automatically increment each time a row is inserted.  It also handles concurrency much better than pretty much anything you could implement manually.

**EDIT:**

Sample of a manual ID value:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable ON

INSERT INTO MyTable (IdField, Col1, Col2, Col3,...)
VALUES
(1234, 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3',...)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable OFF
```

You need to include an explicit field list for the `INSERT`.

Comment: +1 Yes, Identity has logic involving semaphores that prevent two clients from getting a duplicate key. Ease your burden by using features that have been designed, built, and tested.

Comment: @rajah - exactly, don't reinvent the wheel if a great one already exists for free.

Comment: @JNK, but I always dont want idnetity insert. I will have to pass value as a parameter as well. Even if I disabled identity insert before inserting value and after that enable it, even then chances of that logical error are there. Any solution please.

Comment: @JNK, if I am not mis understood you refered Identity() funtion, right ? if not please clarify does it supports identity insert and also custom value ?

Comment: @user - you can use a custom value, and identity insert.  It's not a function, it's a subset of the `int` datatype that auto-incremements.

Comment: @JNK thanks, as I am not aware of that and also not finding correct thing on google can you plese guide a SQL query using this to add vlaue. THANKS

Comment: @JNK, in this approach the chances of that logical error are still there, yet this can decrese these chances. Just considre multiple users attempting insert.

Comment: @user - You could also add a `UNIQUE INDEX` to that field to prevent dupes without needing to handle the logic in your code.

Comment: @JNK, that is the issue for which I posted. These values can be duplicated (as I stated in question) but just in case a new id beign added I want to secure for logical error.

Comment: @user - your use case makes no sense.  How will you allow duplicate ID values but you also want to prevent errors due to duplicates?  Either dupes are allowed or they are not, and you need to build your business processes around that.

Comment: @user576510: you either have custom values always, or use identity always. Don't mix.

Answer (score 1):

Use OUTPUT on your insert to be sure that you have the right value.  If you insert and then select MAX, it is possible that someone could "sneak" in and end up with duplication.  That is, you insert MAX + 1, at the same time someone else inserts MAX + 1 then you select MAX and they select MAX, you both have the same value.  Whereas if you INSERT and use OUTPUT, you'll be sure that you're unique.  This is rarely a problem, but if you have a lot of activity, it can happen (speaking from experience).

**EDIT**

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(
    EmpID int NOT NULL,
    OldVacationHours int,
    NewVacationHours int,
    ModifiedDate datetime);
UPDATE TOP (10) HumanResources.Employee
SET VacationHours = VacationHours * 1.25,
    ModifiedDate = GETDATE() 
OUTPUT inserted.BusinessEntityID,
       deleted.VacationHours,
       inserted.VacationHours,
       inserted.ModifiedDate
INTO @MyTableVar;
--Display the result set of the table variable.
SELECT EmpID, OldVacationHours, NewVacationHours, ModifiedDate
FROM @MyTableVar;
GO
--Display the result set of the table.
SELECT TOP (10) BusinessEntityID, VacationHours, ModifiedDate
FROM HumanResources.Employee;
GO
```

Comment: You can probably avoid this by using the right locking hints, e.g. INSERT table SELECT MAX(col)+1 FROM table WITH (HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK). While this is not fantastic for concurrency, this is cheaper than inserting, checking the output to make sure you got the right value, and if you didn't, deleting and try again (potentially repeat n times). Still not sure why IDENTITY is a problem for the op.

Comment: Locking is the core mechanism that prevents two people from reading the same value and making assumptions about what they can do next. It isn't something you should like or dislike, if it is needed, you need to do it.

Comment: We agree. But if you can avoid the lock, you should. Using OUTPUT facilitates that. What you've suggested in your comment, is to avoid using OUTPUT by locking the table - which I do not agree with.  You wouldn't have to recheck as you've suggested.

Comment: Granted, you've changed your answer considerably since I made my comment, so it's not fair to say what I was suggesting violated the previous version of your answer, which was vague and sample-less. :-)