# Recommendations to Handle MAX(NUM) for multi-user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have one `Tickets` table that contain numbers and another details
When user create a new ticket the new number should be `MAX(Num)+1`
The problem is if there is about 25 users working simultaneously, how can I handle this number for each new ticket
*(if max no. is 1000 then each new ticket will get 1001, because the transactions not committed yet)*
Please note that the user should see the ticket number before commit.

Comment: That's just bad design that will cause you more problems going forward. use auto generated keys and let SQL-Server do what it's good at. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708008/adding-maxvalue1-in-new-row-can-this-be-a-problem

Comment: You can't both a) guarantee that ticket numbers will be sequential; and b) allow multiple concurrent users to create new tickets that they can abandon (choose to not commit).

Comment: @Tanner thanks, Is way helpful with multiple concurrent users? because they should see the ID value before post?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, I believe you should use an [identity column that auto increments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) and then have an additional [bit column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177603.aspx) with a default value to specify that the row is saved/committed:

```
CREATE TABLE Tickets  
(  
 id int IDENTITY(1,1),  
 -- other columns
 isSaved bit DEFAULT 0 
);
```

With this approach a row is created with a unique `id` each time a ticket is made, the default value for `isSaved` will be `false \ 0`. When you get to the stage the ticket is saved/committed, you just set the `isSaved` flag to `true \ 1`.

If required, you could have a clean up task that deletes tickets that weren't saved/committed by checking the value of the `isSaved` column.